# In IIS7 configuration, what file types are affected by the staticContent element?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

How does IIS7 know whether the file being served being static of dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

IIS checks to see if there's a handler mapping for the file extension. If there isn't, the file path is passed to the modules defined in the `StaticFile` handler mapping which will use the `StaticFileModule` to determine if there's a matching mime type.